# Simplest way to remove smaller data set from bigger one in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I looking for easiest way to filter two files.
**INPUT**: *txt files*
File 1 (bigger one):

```
abc111
abc112
abc113
abc114
abc115
...
zbc999
```

File 2 (smaller one):

```
abc111
abc112
abc113
```

**OUTPUT:**
On the output I want to have new file with non-recurring (unique) data set. In other words, in output file must be only those entries from a larger file 1 that are unique and do not occur in a smaller file 2.

BTW:
How to do it easily if the file names are long and difficult to enter them every time the console?

Comment: While this is doable with only standard functionality, the best way I can think of is still extremely painful. So what you want is simply to find a program that can do this easily, which makes the question off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"extremely painful"?

```
@echo off
REM step 1: remove doublettes from file1
echo.>file1.tmp
for /f %%i in (file1.txt) do (
 findstr /x /L "%%i" file1.tmp>nul ||echo %%i>>file1.tmp
)

REM step 2: extract lines that doesn't exist in file2
findstr /v /x /L /g:file2.txt file1.tmp >output.txt

type output.txt
```

Comment: Is there any way to make method to choose file1.txt and file2.txt from popup window?

Comment: Well, **that** would be the "extremely painful" part. But do you know, that you can use the `TAB` key to complete a filename at the command prompt? Enter the first two or three characters and press `TAB` several times, it will toggle through all matching filenames.

Comment: Your basic logic is sound, but this has bugs, one of which cannot be solved. FIND is a poor choice because it will report that `234` matches `1234`. FINDSTR is better because you can specify the `/X` option to match the entire line exactly. It also needs the `/L` option to prevent regex interpretation. But \\ and \" literals within search strings require the leading \ to be escaped as \\. More troubling is a horrific FINDSTR bug that can cause searches with multiple strings of different lengths to sometimes miss matches. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053.

Comment: @dbenham 's last point can be resolved with another `for` to check for one string after another. Ugly and slow, but reliable (?). I didn't get the "But \` and \"` literals..." part - maybe some characters are not shown as intended. (I read the link, but parts of that is (yet) a bit behind my horizon.) I edited my answers to include the first parts of dbenhams comment.

Comment: @Stephan: So... do we agree on "extremely painful" now? ;-) Frankly, batch files is about the most masochistic way to do this. PowerShell at the very least.

Comment: @jon: well - uhm - ok, point for you. But it's not the logic that's painful, but the working around some bugs.

Comment: @Stephan: Agreed. That's just how batch files turn out a lot of the time: the logic is simple, but the execution is another issue entirely.